# Replace sum of upper group levels with value from detail in ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, drilldown

I have a simple .rdl report with a drill down group.

As it stands, when collapsed, the parent row shows the sum of the child rows, which is expected.

However, I am also calculating a "Percentage completed field".  My problem is described in the mock up below.

When everything is expanded, everything is ok.
[All rows expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv8TY.png)

When i collapse some of the rows, that is when the problems start.  The parent row now shows the sum of the collapsed rows which is expected.  However, because I am calculating a percentage, I do not want to show the sum of the percentages, but rather the actual calculated percentage of the collapsed row.

For example, it shows:
[Unwanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA7EY.png)

instead of
[Wanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymHeH.png)

Is this possible?  I imagine I need to write some expression?  The cell value is currently as I dragged it from the dataset:  [Sum(TargetDeviation)] where TargetDeviation is a simple calculated field, actual/target. (=Fields!Tested.Value/Fields!ProgressTarget.Value)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have figured it out using an iif combined with an InScope function.

=iif(InScope("YourGroupName"),Fields!Tested.Value/Fields!ProgressTarget.Value,SUM(Fields!Tested.Value)/SUM(Fields!ProgressTarget.Value))